# mui-rte Issue with On-Screen keyboards on Mobile Phone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, rich-text-editor, rte

Every time I'm typing something the onChange is called successfully with an immutable object containing all the information about the current state of the mui-rte.

But there is some issue with the RTE in mobile phone, The event are getting triggered successfully on key press, also I can see the characters on the screen, but within the onChange the content is missing, unless I add a blank space or any number the word is not recognized.

I'll explain with the difference in behaviour with the help of this table.

| RTE Input Field | RTE State in Desktop | RTE State in Mobile |
| --- | --- | --- |
| q | currentContent:{blockMap:[{text : "q"}] } | currentContent:{blockMap:[{text : ""}] } |
| qwerty ytrewq | currentContent:{blockMap:[{text : "qwerty ytrewq"}] } | currentContent:{blockMap:[{text : "qwerty"}] } |
| qwerty \n ytrewq | currentContent:{blockMap:[{text : "qwerty"}],[text:"ytrewq"] } | currentContent:{blockMap:[{text : "qwerty"}] } |
| 123 | currentContent:{blockMap:[{text : "123"}] } | currentContent:{blockMap:[{text : "123"}] } |
| qwerty฿ | currentContent:{blockMap:[{text : "qwerty฿"}] } | currentContent:{blockMap:[{text : "qwerty"}] } |
| /abcd | currentContent:{blockMap:[{text : "/abcd"}] } | currentContent:{blockMap:[{text : "/"}] } |

฿ -> One blank space

All the keys are not shown.

I hope the issue is clear, on mobile I'm using the default Google keyboard on Crome Browser and the device is Android.
Also earlier I was on version - 1.29.0, and now I've shifted to latest 2.0.1, the issue is in both these versions.

Only Issue here is the value within the onChange event is not correct, otherwise the events are proper.